# How to fix "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently creating a money counter application, but I've got an error on this line: `MessageBox.Show(total);`.
Can someone help me?
Error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'`
Code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/remifuxisi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use ToString() to convert the double to a string.

```
  MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
```